# Embed Video MP4 in html with PHP

Tags: php, html, video

I'm trying to embed a video that I have saved on my site using php.  Im using the following code, but I can't seem to get it to work.  How would this be done?:

HTML:

```
<video controls> 
  <source src="http://mysite2323.com/action/file/download?file_guid=884498" type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

PHP:

```
$mime = $file->getMimeType();
if (!$mime) {
    $mime = "application/octet-stream";
}

$filename = $file->originalfilename;

// fix for IE https issue
header("Pragma: public");

header("Content-type: $mime");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Length: {$file->getSize()}");

while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
flush();
readfile($file->getFilenameOnFilestore());
exit;
```

Comment: Replace `type=video/mp4` to `type="video/mp4"`. See if that works.

Comment: sadly no it doesn't work

Comment: I would assume you would need to add the file extension in the src, you don't have a direct link to the video?

Comment: No I don't.  If I set Content-Disposition to Attachment instead of inline, the video downloads to my computer fine, So I know that works. But I don't want to download it I want to display it on my site.

Comment: Ok so I think I figured out part of the issue. It doesn't display on my MacBook. But if I load the page on my android the video loads.  Does anyone know what can cause this?